# Discord.py: How can I make a toggleable system to turn on/off a message content detection?

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to work on a system where if you run the "AWM" command, the bot will check all further messages from anyone in a given server, if the message contains a key-phrase (in this case being 's') the bot will send "FlyingWiener go brrrrrrrrrrrrr" in the same channel as the message it found. But I don't know why my code isn't working, could I please have some help? Thanks!

````
def MessageContentDetection(): #on_message event definition where it detects "s" in a given message's content
  @bot.event
  def on_message(message):
          if 's' in message.content:
            await message.channel.send("FlyingWiener go brrrrrrrrrrrrr")

variables = {}
Messages = {}

@commands.command() #Activation Command
async def AWM(ctx):
    User = ctx.author
    Owner = ctx.guild.owner
    if User == Owner:
        var = variables.get(ctx.guild.id, 0)
        if var == 0:
            variables[ctx.guild.id] = 1
            await ctx.send("WienerMode Now Active!")
            Messages[ctx.guild.id] = 1
        else:
            await ctx.send("WienerMode is still active Sherlock")
    else:
      await ctx.send(f"Access Denied, No access granted to **{User}**")

@bot.event #Message Send Event
async def on_message(ctx):
  MSG = Messages.get(ctx.guild.id, 0)
  if MSG==1:
    MessageContentDetection()

@commands.command() #Deactivation Command
async def DWM(ctx):
    User = ctx.author
    Owner = ctx.guild.owner
    if User == Owner:
        var = variables.get(ctx.guild.id, 0) 
        if var == 1:
            variables[ctx.guild.id] = 0
            await ctx.send("WienerMode Nolonger Active!")
            Messages[ctx.guild.id] = 0
        else:
            await ctx.send("WienerMode is still off Idiot")
    else:
      await ctx.send(f"Access Denied, No access granted to **{User}**")```
````

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `MessageContentDetection` function, instead you should just check the condition inside the existing `on_message` event itself as the event is running either way. It can be done this way instead:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if Messages.get(message.guid.id, 0) == 1:
        if 's' in message.content:
            await message.channel.send('FlyingWiener go brrrrrrrrrrrrr')
```

This way, if the condition isn't true, the on_message event will be passed and no code runs inside that.